# Loading Image onto Tomcat Server in Android for phoneGap

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to phoneGap. What i want is to upload and then download an image onto a Tomcat server. I found several examples to upload and download pictures but they were all for PHP server. If someone can tell me how to do it for Tomcat Server.From my emulator i upload the image but on the server i don't see anything.If anyone could guide me how to do the same.Thanks.

Comment: There are two buttons,on click of the first the image selected from galary is uploaded onto the server and then on click of the next button it shall get downloaded and shown.